# Central limit theorem - Coin toss

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

We toss $n=200$ Euro coins on the table.

I want to calculate, using the central limit theorem, the probability that at least $110$ coins have tutned on the same side.

$$$$

Do we have to consider one side, without loss of generality, to determine the random variables $X_i$ as follows: \begin{equation*}X_i=\begin{cases} 
1 , & \text{coin } i \text{ shows head}\\ 
0 , & \text{coin } i \text{ does not show head}
\end{cases}\end{equation*}

Or do we not have to consider one specific side of the coin? But how would the random variables be then defined?

Comment: The probability that at least $110$ show $H$ is the same as the probability that at least $110$ show $T$ so if you just do one side all you have to do is double the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can define $X_i$ as you suggest though not all Euros have a head (is it the map side they all have? or the other side which sometimes has a head?) Let's define $X_i$ as an indicator of the map side, so you either want at least $110$ or no more than $90$ map sides showing

You then want $\mathbb P \left(\sum X_i \ge 110\right)+\mathbb P \left(\sum X_i \le 90\right)$

Assuming independence, you can then use the binomial distribution for an exact calculation, or a Gaussian approximation with a cuttoffs at $90.5$ and $109.5$ (or using symmetry, double no more than $90.5$).  The probability would be almost $18\%$

For example in R:

```
> pbinom(90, size=200, prob=0.5) + 1 - pbinom(109, size=200, prob=0.5)
[1] 0.178964

> 2 * pnorm(90.5, mean=200*0.5, sd=sqrt(200*0.5*0.5)) 
[1] 0.1791092
```

Comment: I understand! I wnat also to calculate which has to be at least the value of $n$ such that with probability $\geq 0.95$ at at least $45\%$ und at most at $55\%$ of the coins "head" is shown. I have to use again the CLT. Is it as follows? \begin{align*}\mathbb{P}\left (n\cdot 45\%\leq S_{n}\leq n\cdot 55\%\right )\geq 0.95  &\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}\left ( S_{n}\leq n\cdot 0.55\right )-\mathbb{P}\left ( S_{n}\leq n\cdot 0.45\right )\geq 0.95 \\ & \Rightarrow \Phi \left (\frac{ 0.55n-n\mu }{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\right )-\Phi \left (\frac{ 0.45n-n\mu }{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\right )\geq 0.95\end{align*}

Comment: If this is correct how could we continue?

Comment: @MaryStar Use $\Phi \left (\frac{ 0.45n-0.5n }{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\right )=1-\Phi \left (\frac{ 0.55n-0.5n }{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\right )$ and then the inverse standard normal cdf $\Phi^{-1}()$

Comment: So, does it hold that $\Phi (a)-\Phi (b) = \Phi (b-a)$ Or how do get that?

Comment: @MaryStar That looks very wrong

Comment: Ah I misread your previous formula!

Comment: I understand!! So, we get $n\geq 384.16$ which means that $n$ must be at least $385$, right?

Comment: I want to ask also something else: $$$$ A hotel has 800 beds and it is known that 10% of the bookings are canceled. To achieve a complete occupancy, the management decides to confirm more bookings than beds are available. We assume that people decide independently whether they make their booking. I have defined the random variable $X_i$ with \begin{equation*}X_i=\begin{cases} 
1 , & \text{person } i \text{ is showing up}\\ 
0 , & \text{person } i \text{ is not showing up}
\end{cases}\end{equation*}  
We have that $\mu=p=0,9$ and $\sigma^2=p(1-p)=0,9\cdot 0,1=0,09$.

Comment: From the CLT we have the following: 
$$\mathbb{P}\left (S_{820}\leq 800\right )=P\left (\frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{820}X_i-n\mu} }{\displaystyle{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}}\leq \frac{\displaystyle{800-n\mu} }{\displaystyle{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}}\right )  \approx \Phi \left (\frac{800-n\mu }{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\right )  =\Phi \left (\frac{800-820\cdot 0,9 }{\sqrt{820\cdot 0,09}}\right )  \approx \Phi \left (7.2171\right )$$  
Is this correct? Can the result $\Phi \left (7.2171\right )$ be correct? Or is the argument of $\Phi$ too large?

Answer (score 1):

By using the CLT:

Let $\sum_{i=1}^{200} X_i$ be the number of "heads" in $200$ coin flips. Hence, 
$\sum X_i \sim Bin (n,p)$ or 
$$
\sum X_i\overset{approx.}{\sim}\mathcal{N}  (np, np(1-p)),
$$
thus \begin{align}
\mathbb{P}( \sum X_i \ge 110) &= 1- \mathbb{P}( \sum X_i < 110)\\
                              &\approx 1- \Phi\left( \frac{109.5 - np }{\sqrt{npq}} \right). 
\end{align}
For tails it will be the same calculations. Thus assuming a fair coin and independent tosses, the probability of the event if interest approx equals
$$
2 \left( \approx 1- \Phi\left( \frac{109.5 - 100 }{\sqrt{50}} \right) \right)
$$

Comment: Ah I see! I wnat also to calculate which has to be at least the value of $n$ such that with probability $\geq 0.95$ at at least $45\%$ und at most at $55\%$ of the coins "head" is shown. I have to use again the CLT. Is it as follows? \begin{align*}\mathbb{P}\left (n\cdot 45\%\leq S_{n}\leq n\cdot 55\%\right )\geq 0.95  &\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}\left ( S_{n}\leq n\cdot 0.55\right )-\mathbb{P}\left ( S_{n}\leq n\cdot 0.45\right )\geq 0.95 \\ & \Rightarrow \Phi \left (\frac{ 0.55n-n\mu }{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\right )-\Phi \left (\frac{ 0.45n-n\mu }{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\right )\geq 0.95\end{align*}

Comment: If this is correct how could we continue?

Comment: Use $ \Phi(-\alpha) = 1 - \Phi(\alpha)$ and then you will have to solve a quadratic equation w.r.t. $n$.

Comment: I got it! Thanks! I have also an other question at an other problem: $$$$ A hotel has 800 beds and it is known that 10% of the bookings are canceled. To achieve a complete occupancy, the management decides to confirm more bookings than beds are available. We assume that people decide independently whether they make their booking.
Using the CLT I want to calculate the probability that all people that show up in the hotel, for whom a bed has been reserved, will also receive a bed if 820 bookings have been confirmed.

Comment: I have defined the random variable $X_i$ with \begin{equation*}X_i=\begin{cases} 
1 , & \text{person } i \text{ is showing up}\\ 
0 , & \text{person } i \text{ is not showing up}
\end{cases}\end{equation*}  
We have that $\mu=p=0,9$ and $\sigma^2=p(1-p)=0,9\cdot 0,1=0,09$.

Comment: From the CLT we have the following: 
$$\mathbb{P}\left (S_{820}\leq 800\right )=P\left (\frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{820}X_i-n\mu} }{\displaystyle{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}}\leq \frac{\displaystyle{800-n\mu} }{\displaystyle{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}}\right )  \approx \Phi \left (\frac{800-n\mu }{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\right )  =\Phi \left (\frac{800-820\cdot 0,9 }{\sqrt{820\cdot 0,09}}\right )  \approx \Phi \left (7.2171\right )$$  
Is everything correct? Can the result $\Phi \left (7.2171\right )$ be correct? Or is the argument of $\Phi$ too large?

Comment: Looks fine. Just don't forget the continuity correction, and consider to ask a new question as it does not directly related to the original one.

Comment: What do you mean by continuity correction? But how can we calculate $\Phi \left (7.2171\right )$ ? Because at the most table we see only small arguments.

Comment: 1. Plug in $800.5$ instead of $800$ . 2. for $x\ge 3.5$, $ \Phi(x) \approx 1$.

Comment: Why do we have to use $800.5$ ? Is it wrong to use $800$ ?

Comment: Because Normal is continuous dist. and can receive any value on $\mathbb{R}$, while Binomial dist. only $0,1,...,n$, so you have to account for the "in between" of these integers

Comment: So, if we take $800$ instead of $800.5$ is it wrong because we don't consider the $800$ ? I haven't really understoof that. Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: No, because you consider "only half" of the 800. What represent values in $(800, 800.5)$? $801$? see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction)

Comment: Ah ok! And do we have to do this also in the original question with the coins?

Comment: Yes, as I did in my answer

Comment: @V.Vancak since we use $\approx$ for computing $\Phi$ anyway, can't we just ignore the condition of integer support for Binomial and simply use (in this case) $\Phi((110-100)/\sqrt(50)) = \Phi(\sqrt(2))$

Comment: @Alex Clearly, since you anyway use an approximation, then the continuity correction is usually less important than the validity of the approximation itself (that depends mainly on $n$). Hence, it is also a matter of convection. Personally, I would use the correction for small $n$, in order to give "sufficient" probability mass to $110$ itself.